# Detect the end of a request

Tags: fastify

Is it possible to detect the end of a request? I'm writing a plugin/middleware (with `fastify-plugin`) and I'm currently getting all the asset requests when I just want the route itself.

In Express I can place my middleware after the body parser and everything else so I get **one** request object. I'm quite new to `fastify` and I like it a lot.

Comment: Do you have some code? Maybe this example could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54426638/3309466

Comment: That'll probably work, thanks! My plugin is done but maybe it'll benefit from that code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify or save data in request object in fastify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54425219/modify-or-save-data-in-request-object-in-fastify)