# Modify or save data in request object in fastify

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I use nestjs to build a REST API.

I have a middleware which loads data from redis cache and should save it in the request object to access it in the controller function.

If i use express as engine it works, but with fastify it doesn't work. The data is undefined in the controller function.

The code looks like:

```
function mymiddleware(req, res, next) => {
    req.data = {...};
    next();
};
```

Comment: Probably not what you wanted to hear but I'm able to reproduce this issue in a brand new scaffolded Nest app with the most basic possible middleware. There seems to be a bunch of issues currently open with the Fastify adapter so I'm wondering if it might not be production ready at this point. I'd open an issue on Github for this as it seems like show stopping functionality to me

Comment: How do you register that middleware?

Comment: I registering the middleware how it is described in the nestjs docs.

Comment: @Jesse can you post a link to your issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is a simple working example:

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })

fastify.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('middy')
  req.data = { hello: 'world' }
  next();
})

fastify.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`hello ${req.raw.data.hello}`)
})

fastify.listen(3000)
```

I think that your problem is due to the `req` object: in middleware (registered using `.use` you will get the standard Node.js request, instead of augmented HTTPRequest in the fastify handler.

So, you can access the low-level Http request with `.raw` field.